# fabric.api.sudo() returning empty stderr on error condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko, invoke, fabric

I am new to fabric.
I am running a command as `res = fabric.api.sudo(f"pip install {something}",user=user)`
I expect the command to return stderr or abort when the package/version is not found i.e. pip install fails. However I am getting a res.return_code=0, res.stderr, as empty on an error condition. I do get the ERROR message on stdout. Is it expected behavior ? How can I make the stderr have the error condition and the correct return_code?

**Version:**
Using Fabric3 with version 1.14.post1

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command had multiple commands with pipes. So needed to leverage PIPESTATUS to get the right return code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/interactivity.html#combining-the-two), the default value of `combine_stderr` is `True`, which means that *stderr* is combined in a single stream with *stdout*. If you want to retrieve output on *stderr* separately, you need to explicitly set `combined_stderr` to `False` (and `pty` to `False`):

```
>>> res = fabric.operations.sudo('sh -c "echo hello; echo world >&2"', pty=False, combine_stderr=False)
[rocket] sudo: sh -c "echo hello; echo world >&2"
[rocket] out: hello
[rocket] out: [rocket] err: world
[rocket] err:


>>> res.stdout
'hello'
>>> res.stderr
'world'
```